# Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{a\cos^2x + b\sin^2x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I don't know how to deal with this integral
$$I=\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{a\cos^2x + b\sin^2x}\,dx$$
I reached the step

$$I
=\displaystyle\ \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{a + b\tan^2x}dx$$

Now what should I do? Please help.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before. You'll need to edit your post to include your working so we can see where you are having issues and so we don't use techniques you haven't learnt yet. Anyway, dividing through by $\cos^{2}(x)$ then using a substitution might work.

Comment: You can assume $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, since otherwise the integral doesn't converge. Evaluate the definite integral in Deepak Suwalka's answer using residue calculus. If that doesn't make sense, see @Mattos's comment.

Comment: This duplicate answered your question: [Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{a + \sin^2 \theta}$ using the residue theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390033/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-frac1a-sin2-theta-using) (your integral is very easily deducible from that one)

Answer (score 2):

Now substitute

$\displaystyle\ u=\tan x \implies x= tan^{-1} u \implies dx=\frac{1}{1+u^2} du$

$\displaystyle\ =\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+u^2)(a + bu^2)}du$

[Partial Fractions](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-2/indefinite-integration/advanced-methods-of-integration/partial-fractions)

$\displaystyle\ =\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+u^2)(a + bu^2)}du= \frac{1}{a-b} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+u^{2}} - b \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{a+bu^{2}} \right)$

Evaluating

$\displaystyle\ =\frac{1}{a-b} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+u^{2}} - b \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{a+bu^{2}} \right)$

$\displaystyle\ =\frac{1}{a-b} \left([\tan x]_0^{\infty} - b \left(\frac{\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{b}x}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{ab}} \right]_0^{\infty}\right)$

*Put the Values*

Comment: This answer makes assumptions about $a$ and $b$...

Comment: How do you substitute $x=\infty$ into $\tan x$?

Comment: Is ti possible to do it if I put $e^{\cos^2x}$? I mean $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{a\cos^2x + b\sin^2x}e^{c\cos^2x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

put $\displaystyle I = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2 x}{a\cos^2 x+b\sin^2 x}dx$ and $\displaystyle J = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{a\cos^2 x+b\sin^2 x}dx$

$\displaystyle aI+bJ = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: How do you know that the sum adds to $\pi/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Continue with
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{a + b\tan^2x}dx
= &\ \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(1-  \frac{b\sec^2x}{a + b\tan^2x}\bigg)dx\\
=& \ \frac1{a-b}\bigg( \frac\pi2- \frac\pi2 \sqrt{\frac ba}\bigg)
=\frac\pi{2(a+\sqrt{ab})}
\end{align}